# Alternate Elements Of Array (Please Help)

Tags: arrays, kotlin

How to print alternate elements of an array in Kotlin. for example elements of an array are (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) then the output should be (1,3,5,7,9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).filterIndexed { idx,_ -> idx % 2 == 0 }`

will do the job. You might also want to have a look at the fold method on lists that will help you carry out more complex tasks.

Comment: Thank You for the idea. I think at last (.forEach{println(it)}) this should come -----> listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).filterIndexed{ idx,_ -> idx % 2 == 0 }.forEach{println(it)}
}